# How to unstall sql develpoer from windows?

Tags: sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/571N9.png)

I am unable to unstall sql developer from my pc please someone help....

Answer (score 0):

SQL Developer is not "installed", the files are just downloaded/unzipped. If you want to get rid of it then just delete the files/folders